# Compile Error: Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent

Tags: excel, xml, vba, class

I am trying to create a custom Class Object in my VBA project that handles an XML Document created from the output of a web app.

The structure of the XML is always the same, and the same nodes are always present. So I wanted to create several class properties that would essentially act like shortcuts to certain node values or turn a list of node values into an array (easier to copy into excel).

I am running into the error:

> Compile error:
>
> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter

The property that triggers the error is

```vb
Property Let Headers(Column As Long, Name As String)
    MyDoc_Headers.ChildNodes(Column - 1).ChildNodes(1).nodeTypedValue = Name
End Property
Property Get Headers(Column As Long) As Variant
    Headers = MyDoc_Headers.ChildNodes(Column - 1).ChildNodes(1).nodeTypedValue
End Property
```

This property is a shortcut to Read/Write the name value of the headers in the document. The Node `MyDoc_Headers` has the structure:

```xml
<Headers>
    <Header>
        <DisplayAt>DisplayOption</DisplayAt>
        <Name>HeaderName</Name>
    </Header>
</Headers>
```

Depending on what the user requested from the web app, the document has a different number of Headers but it is always two or more. This is why I ask for `Column` as an argument of the `Headers` property. My idea was to use that as an index to point to different childNodes of the `Headers` Node.

The idea is that the user could write `.Headers(1) = "Header 1"` and the class property would put that value into the `Name` Element of the `Header` Node in the `Headers` Node.

I must be implementing this in the wrong way. **What is the correct way to implement a property like this?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/definitions-of-property-procedures-for-the-same-property-are-inconsistent

Comment: It would be simpler to write a `Sub SetHeader(Column As Long, Name As String)` method in your class.  The call is not quite as nice but it would be just as functional.

Comment: @TimWilliams That article says every parameter be the corresponding types. Is the error caused because `Get Headers` is returning Variant but `Name` in `Let Headers` is a String?

Comment: Assuming variant results, `Property Let Headers(Column As Long, Name As Variant)` with a variant `Name` variable would meet the requirements of the help reference above: *"The parameter type of the extra parameter of the `Property Let` must match the return type of the corresponding `Property Get` procedure."* @Toddleson